# Embedding Video in SVG issues

Tags: html, svg, video

I want to embed a video into an SVG to be displayed on a website, but I'm facing some issues with both playback and also responsive sizing.  the code is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1050 550" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1050 550;" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:bx="https://boxy-svg.com">
  <style type="text/css">
.background{fill:#4D4D4D;}
.box{stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
  <rect id="Background" class="background" width="1050" height="550" bx:origin="0 0">
    <title>background</title>
  </rect>
  <foreignObject>
<video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="800" controls="" style="position: fixed; left: 101px; top: 51px;">>
<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
</foreignObject>
  <rect id="Box" class="box" width="800" height="450" y="50" style="fill: none;" x="100" bx:origin="0 0">
    <title>background</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

RE: sizing - I've tried using "vw" and "em" sizing conventions for this but when I do, the video doesn't show at all.

RE: playback - there is no way I can add "controls" to the foreignObject class - it just gives me an error and won't render the SVG.

Can anyone help or think of any ideas here?  Would be really grateful :)

Comment: I can see that you have a XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`) in your code – Is this supposed to be an independent document or a part of a HTML page? In the case of the later, how is the SVG document added/included in the HTML document?

Comment: @chrwahl - yes it's an independent document - it's being included in the HTML as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Then main issue is that the `<foreignObject>` should have a size, just like other SVG elements.

I couldn't get the video to show, so I picked another one.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 340 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="Background" class="background" width="340"
    height="200" fill="gray" />
  <foreignObject width="320" height="180" x="10" y="10">
    <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="320"
      height="180" controls>
      <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </foreignObject>
  <rect width="340" height="100" y="100" fill="black"
    opacity=".3" pointer-events="none" />
</svg>
```

## Update

I'm not able to reproduce the error "error on line 14 at column 56: Specification mandates value for attribute controls", but make sure that the control attribute has a value (or, like here `controls=""`), now that it is an XML document.

In the following example I have the SVG document and a HTML document. Both documents have a stylesheet that behaves responsive at 300 and 400 pixel width. This seams to work fine.

##### SVG document (video.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 340 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .backgrond {
        fill: gray;
      }
      @media (min-width: 300px) {
        .background {
          fill: orange;
        }
      }
  </style>
  <rect class="background" width="340" height="200" fill="gray" />
  <foreignObject width="320" height="180" x="10" y="10">
    <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="320"
      height="180" controls="">
      <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </foreignObject>
  <rect width="340" height="100" y="100" fill="black"
    opacity=".3" pointer-events="none" />
</svg>
```

##### HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .video {
        width: 100%;
      }
      @media (min-width: 400px) {
        .video {
          width: 400px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object class="video" type="image/svg+xml" data="video.svg"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - unfortunately this doesn't really resolve either issue.  "controls" still gives the same error and the Video isn't responsive when I resize the browser window :(. Thanks for trying though

Comment: @NathanTaylor What kind of error are you getting? Are these controls that you made with JavaScript or the build in controls?

Comment: It's just the built in controls but I have a feeling it's to do with the SVG side of things with this - very strange.  The error I get is: 

"error on line 14 at column 56: Specification mandates value for attribute controls"

Comment: @NathanTaylor I updated my answer. Make sure to run this from a webserver (not from the file system).

Comment: Thanks @chrwahl - it's still not working - controls show at all :/. I'm using VSCode to test it.  Maybe it's just one of those things that just won't happen :/  Appreciate your help though